# How to create members from constructor arguments?

Tags: javascript, constructor

I want to create some object members based on a constructor argument, but it's not working as expected. No members are created. How can I achieve this?

```
function Foo(parameters = []) {
    parameters.forEach(function(e) {
        this[e.name] = e.initial;
    });
};

const p = [{
    "name": "sensitivity",
    "initial": 50
}];

const f = new Foo(p);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `this` keyword within the **callback** function provided by `forEach` method, but the `this` of that function is just a **reference** to the window object.

You can read more about the scope of `this` in javascript in this [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

### 1. Use `bind` method.

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

```js
function Foo(parameters = []) {
    parameters.forEach(function(e) {
        this[e.name] = e.initial;
    }.bind(this));
};

const p = [{
    "name": "sensitivity",
    "initial": 50
}];

const f = new Foo(p);
console.log(f);
```

### 2. Use `arrow` functions.

Until `arrow` functions, every `new` **function** defined its own `this` value.

For instance, `this` can be a new object in the case of a constructor.

```js
function Person(age){
  this.age=age;
  console.log(this);
}
let person=new Person(22);
```

Or `this` can **points** to the `base` object if the function created can be accessed like `obj.getAge()`.

```js
let obj={
  getAge:function(){
    console.log(this);
    return 22;
  }
}
console.log(obj.getAge());
```

An `arrow` function does not create its own `this`, it's just used the `this` value of the `enclosing` execution `context`. In the other hand, `arrow` function uses `this` of parent scope.

```js
function Foo(parameters = []) {
    parameters.forEach((e) => {
        this[e.name] = e.initial;
    });
};

const p = [{
    "name": "sensitivity",
    "initial": 50
}];

const f = new Foo(p);
console.log(f);
```

Comment: @ziggystar, in your example `this` is a reference to the window object.

Answer (score 1):

You are having the classic "`this` is not what you think it is" problem. Using an arrow function is a way of solving the problem, as it retains the `this` reference from parent scope.

```js
function Foo(parameters = []) {
    parameters.forEach(e => this[e.name] = e.initial);
};

const p = [{
    "name": "sensitivity",
    "initial": 50
}];

const f = new Foo(p);

console.log(f);
```

Comment: So `this` refers to the lambda here?

Comment: @ziggystar, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work. This link provides a lot of answer in order to understand better about `this`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are experiencing here is a problem with `this`.

You are referencing `this` inside of a function in a callback but the `this` of that inner function refers to the `parameters` object rather than the `Foo` instance.

For example if you were to add after your loop this:

```
console.log(parameters)
```

I suspect you would find that the `parameters` object itself was modified to have a name property with the value `'50'`.

There are a couple of ways to solve this and they all have to do with preserving the correct this that you are expecting.

### Use a lambda function

Alter your loop function to be a lambda function instead of a basic function like so:

```
parameters.forEach((e) => {
    this[e.name] = e.initial;
});
```

The primary difference between a lambda function and a standard function is that a lambda function automatically preserves the `this` of its parent scope.

### Bind your function

You can also bind the function to use a specific `this` rather than the default, which is the caller object.

```
parameters.forEach((function (e) {
    this[e.name] = e.initial;
}).bind(this));
```

Calling `.bind(obj)` on a function will return a new function where `obj` is always the `this` when it is called.

### Capture the outer scope explicitly

Its also common to just set the `this` from the outer-scope into its own variable and reference that directly.

```
var self = this;
parameters.forEach(function (e) {
    self[e.name] = e.initial;
});
```

These are the basic ways to capture and use `this` appropriately.

### Alternative

I also want to add that other than the `this` bug you are experiencing you may want to consider a different approach to your goal entirely. Specifically you may want to consider using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to get the behavior you are looking for. This may look like this:

```
const f = new Foo(p)
Object.assign(f, { sensitivity: 50 })
```

Comment: The solutions appear to be correct, but `this` refers to the global window object, as stated by Alexandru. I've just checked this.

Comment: That shouldn't matter, you should be able to add properties onto the global window object as well. It should have the same behavior in this case.